# Finding sequential Numbers

Tags: c#, sql, math, coding-style

I have a set of numbers `List<int>` (for example) : 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 12, 13, 14, 15, 20, 22, 24, 28, 29, 30

I want to have them grouped as sequential like :

```
Sequence1 = from 1 amount 1 (1)
Sequence2 = from 3 amount 3 (3, 4, 5)
Sequence3 = from 7 amount 1 (7)
Sequence4 = from 12 amount 4 (12, 13, 14, 15)
Sequence5 = from 20 amount 1 (20)
Sequence6 = from 22 amount 1 (22)
Sequence7 = from 24 amount 1 (24)
Sequence8 = from 28 amount 3 (28, 29, 30)
```

I know how to do it with a for and checking for each number. Is there an more elegant way or an algorithm, or some sql/lambda command that would help me ?

Comment: A for loop is the simplest way I can think of. You probably could do it with LINQ, but that would most likely be much uglier.

Comment: Why not foreach? Idk what do you think is more "elegant"?

Comment: after reading this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139323/finding-continuous-ranges-in-a-set-of-numbers i completelly missed that way (for example) so I thought there may be a more elegant solution like check for the number - index of an array or something like that. I simply don't know if foreach is the best way.

Comment: Are your numbers sorted in the input?

Comment: Bart, how are your "from" and "amount" values determined? Is it by another function of based on your list?

Comment: @MPelletier The subsequences he wants are those where each item is 1 larger than the previous.

Comment: Also, are there limit cases? Can numbers from list be excluded?

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Then why is amount 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 3, and not 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6...? I just don't see his algorithm here...

Comment: i want a pack of numbers that are correlative, get the first number of the sequence and the amount. Ordering the sequence beforehand is a valid option. I just want to get the base number and the amount of number correlatives after theres a gap.

Comment: You are aware that even if you find a 'shorter' way of expressing this, it still comes down to a loop?  And as it's a very specifica and ightly bounded problem, writing a simple loop over the ordered list is most likely the most efficient way of doing it.

Comment: @MPelletier:  The value following amount in his output is the number of items in each sub-sequence.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I had figured as much, I just didn't know what made the amount what it was. I finally got it with Bart's last explanation: it's the number of consecutive items starting at a certain value.

Comment: @jsobo the reason I downvoted your answer is that you posted how to extract a subsequence where you already know the start and length, not how to find *sequential* numbers in the given sequence. I commented on sll's equivalent answer, but he deleted it before you you noticed the downvote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the input is sorted, and you really want to avoid a `foreach` loop, you can use:

```
list.Select((value,index)=>new {value,index}).GroupBy(x=>x.value-x.index,x=>x.value).Select(g=>g.AsEnumerable())
```

One could also write a general helper method:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> SplitBetween<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Func<T,T,bool> predicate)
{
  T previous=default(T);
  List<T> list=new List<T>();
  int index=0;
  foreach(T current in sequence)
  {
    if((index>0)&&predicate(previous,current))
    {
      yield return list.ToArray();
      list.Clear();
    }
    list.Add(current);
    previous=current;
    index++;
  }
  if(list.Count>0)
    yield return list.ToArray();
}
```

And then use it with `list.SplitBetween((previous,current) => previous+1 != current)`

Comment: +1 And you may as well provide the code to sort the list as it's trivial.

Comment: @Yuck No that wouldn't work. I think for `1, 4, 2, 3` the expected output is `(1) (4) (2,3)` and not `(1,2,3,4)` as sorting would return.

Comment: Excelent, except the zeros in the return...  where they come from?

Comment: What zeros are you talking about?

Comment: that returns all elements, i just want the base number and count.
like: Dictionary<int, int>()
where the key is the number (value) and the value is the amount of numbers after the key that are sequential

Comment: Then add a `Select(group=>new {group.First(),group.Count()})`. In your examples you listed the elements in each group, so I thought you were interested in them.

Comment: Good Idea, unfortunately in all groups containing more than 1 element, there is a trailing `0`. How comes that?

Comment: @Fischermaen I can't reproduce any trailing `0`s.

Comment: I get the trailing zeros too (in some sequence) if you use my example, you will see trailing zeros in 2 sequences.

Comment: @Bart I don't get any `0`s with your example. My whole code: http://nopaste.info/a276ed9200_nl.html running in LinqPad 4.31 (32 bit)

Comment: I do not get any trailing zeroes when I run the code, either.

Comment: That's funny. I test it under Windows 7, .NET 4 and I get in every seequence containing more than 1 item a trailing `0`.

Comment: Same here, Win7 .NET 4 - All sequence containing more than 1 item has a trailing 0 :S... bug? I don't set as the answer because it doesn't work on 'some systems (?) ' still +1

Comment: @Bart The capacity is larger than the size of these collections. If you check the `count` it is small enough to exclude the trailing `0`s. That's just like `List<T>` has an underlying array that's larger than than the size of the list due to its size doubling growth strategy. The only reason why you see those `0`s is because you peek at private data with your debugger. If enumerate the sequences you won't get them.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that this is very "elegant", but here is my suggestion, hopefully it helps you:

```
var list = new List<int> { 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 12, 13, 14, 15, 20, 22, 24, 28, 29, 30 };

int offset = 0;
int sequence = 0;
do
{
    int offset1 = offset;
    var subList = list.Skip(offset).TakeWhile((item, index) => (index == 0) || (item == (list[offset1 + index - 1] + 1))).ToList();
    offset += subList.Count();
    sequence++;
    Debug.WriteLine("Sequence {0} from {1} amount {2} ({3})", sequence, subList[0], subList.Count(), string.Join(" ", subList));
}
while (offset < list.Count);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int n = 12;//your number
int x = list.IndexOf(n);
var result = list.Skip(x).TakeWhile((value, index) => value - index == n);
```