# how to find the number ranges in a set of numbers in access

Tags: ms-access

i read the article [Finding continuous ranges in a set of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139323/finding-continuous-ranges-in-a-set-of-numbers) but how to display it in a query in MS access as a summary  for example :- if i have a set of numbers with continuous ranges 73780 to 73850 and 74000 to 74150 and etc.....and if the numbers from 73851 to 73999 are  missing  , i want to display only the number ranges present in my set of numbers in a tables as follows  73780 -73850  and 74000-74150 are present.i don t need the missing numbers.i just want the continuous ranges present in the set of numbers in a specific column of my table .please help me.. i search in the web.but i could not find a answer suitable for me to do with it MS Access

|number ranges present|

|    73780 - 73850    |
|    74000 - 74150    |

Answer (score 1):

That's a clever method in the link.

So write the records ordered to a table with an AutoNumber, update field Diff, and use this query:

```
Select Min(Number), Max(Number)
From NumberTable
Group By Diff
```